# Using multiple UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to "force" this code to run through every line and update every line that matches the statement above..

```
if(isset($itemID1) && isset($itemID2) && isset($itemID3) && isset($itemID4) && isset($itemID5) && isset($itemID6) && isset($itemID7) && isset($itemID8) && isset($itemID9) && isset($itemID10)){    
        $upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status/ADM', verification='No'";
        if($CalDate !=''){
            $upd.= ",CalDate='$CalDate'";
        }
        if($DueDate !=''){
            $upd.= ",DueDate='$DueDate'";
        }
        if($groupid1 != 0){
            $upd.= " WHERE groupid IN ('$groupid1')";
        }
        if($groupid2 != 0){
            $upd.= " WHERE groupid IN ('$groupid2')";
        }
        if($groupid1 == 0){
            $upd.= " WHERE itemid IN ('$itemID1')";
        }
        if($groupid2 == 0){
            $upd.= " WHERE itemid IN ('$itemID2')";
        }
    }
```

Known errors: Error could not update data reason: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE itemid IN ('143')' at line 1

Either that or the script will only update the first line that it passes by. As for groupid1 != 0

Comment: And.. what is going wrong? What are the errors? You do know you can't have the `WHERE` multiple times in 1 query right? You should add them with `AND`

Comment: @putvande Error could not update data reason: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE itemid IN ('143')' at line 1

Comment: What's the final value of $upd?

Comment: maybe you have to concatenate this strings insted of setting them ? i dont know php but in this case you have to have this one `$upd. += ",DueDate='$DueDate'"` insted of `$upd.= ",DueDate='$DueDate'";`

Comment: Either the error or only one of the updates will get through. I've updated the text @Reeno

Comment: @The concatenating in PHP works like OP has it.

Comment: Yeah the duedate/caldate isn't making any problem here.. It's the groupid's that is bugging out @The

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely to be where you build your `WHERE` clauses.

It is probably due to the fact that you are adding multiple `WHERE` clauses into your statement.  Your SQL statement can only contain one `WHERE` clause.

For example, if `groupid1` and `groupid2` are not 0 then you will get this statement:

```
SELECT ... WHERE groupid IN ('$groupid1') WHERE groupID IN ('$groupid2')
```

This is obviously invalid.  You need to instead add a single `WHERE` clause and then add parameters using `AND` or `OR` to separate them as appropriate:

```
SELECT ... WHERE groupid IN ('$groupid1') OR groupID IN ('$groupid2')
```

Comment: In this case you dont have both Where clause because your _IF_ looks like a switch @Snoken

Comment: @The you are incorrect.  Both $groupid1 and $groupid2 will be either zero or non-zero, in which case at least 2 `IF` statements will be true and this will result in two `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: The problem is that I'm sending 10 values via input to this php file. Then I want it to scan every value. For each value that contains of a groupID change the status of that group. At the same time I want the script to UPDATE all values without any groupID but for those only individually

Comment: @Snoken You may wish to raise this as a separate question.  I believe that your query as to why you are receiving an error message has been answered successfully.

Comment: Yeah! I will try it out tomorrow and hopefully some results!